# Unable to pass argument to argon2 command

Tags: linux, debian, password, hashsum

According to the manual of `argon2` (Debian package), it says to pass the password from standard input. However, when I follow the instructions and attempt

```
echo -n "password" | argon2 salt "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"-t 4 -e
```

the program simply returns `Error: unknown argument`.

What am I missing here?
The manual says

> The  supplied salt (the first argument to the command) must be at least 8 octets in length, and the password is supplied on standard input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument, the salt value, should be the actual salt that you want to use. Therefore, your command should probably look like

```
echo -n "password" |
argon2 "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" -t 4 -e
```

if the string of `a` characters is your salt. Note also the space between the salt string and the `-t` option.

This literal command would output

```
$argon2i$v=19$m=4096,t=4,p=1$YWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYWFhYQ$9rVLOMSIM9ehkD8zj0aK62CZhchXpDxV/gKcBUQCnbQ
```